# Audit Remote Windows Servers Starting/Stopping Process History

Tags: windows, logging, group-policy, windows-server

I've been tasked with auditing and logging Windows processes when they start and stop.  I'm planning on using Windows Advanced Group Policy auditing feature for this.  And my belief is that starting and stopping processes should be reported back to the Group Policy server.  And hopefully stored in Windows Event Viewer on said Group Policy server.

However in practice that doesn't seem to work.  The Group Policy will allow those events to be stored locally on any remote server.  But those events aren't reported back to the Group Policy server, as I would expect.

IWhat am I missing or not understanding?

Comment: Do some research on security auditing in Windows. The audit events are always logged on the machine where the event occurs. There are tools for aggregating this data centrally once captured.

Comment: I was under the impression that this functionality was built into group policy.  I'm aware there is log forwarding.  But I'm not sure that's exactly what I want.

Comment: Yes, you configure security auditing though group policy. No, that doesn't change where the logging events are generated and therefore stored.